# How can I make that variable to be lowerCase in Yaml?

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have that value

```
BucketName: ${self:custom.s3BucketName}-firmware-${self:provider.stage}
```

And the name of the stage is Uat and I will get an error because can not contain uppercase.

how can I make that ${self:provider.stage} lowerCase, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) that will do this.

If the list of stage names is fixed, you could create a map of the stage name to its lower-case version. Then user [Fn::FindInMap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) to map from the stage name to what the string you actually want.

If the list of stage names isn't fixed, you'll have to write a macro that calls a lambda to do the conversion for you. You then use [Fn::Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html) to use the macro.